# How to count 2 fields at the same time?

Tags: javascript, html

I have some input with 3 values - entrance price, extra (in percent), price
It calculates by the formula: **input price** * **per percentage extra** = **price**

Here is my code:

HTML

```js
function sum() {
    var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('enterence_price').value;
    var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('extra').value;
    var result = parseFloat(txtFirstNumberValue) / 100 * parseFloat(txtSecondNumberValue);
    if (!isNaN(result)) {
        document.getElementById('price').value = result.toFixed(2);
    }

}
```

```html
<label>Enterence Price<br></label>
<input type="text" id="enterence_price" onkeyup="sum();">
<br>
<label>extra%<br></label>
<input type="text" id="extra" value="120%" onkeyup="sum();">
<br>

<label>Price<br></label>
<input type="text" id="price" onkeyup="sum();">
<br>
```

Now I need when I change the value in the "**Price**" input - my extra value should change automatically, the **entrance price** should not change
This is second formula:
Extra price =(price/entrance price)*100%

Comment: What is the specific problem you have that is blocking about modify that code?

Comment: Looks like you need a different function for your `keyup` Event on `#price`. I would really use `oninput` so the Client can paste if they want to. Your formula is `extra = price/entrance_price*100`. You should separate your JavaScript from your HTML. That way your JavaScript is easier to maintain... and is cached. Algebra classes may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the `this` keyword into your function, so you can detect which input has been triggered.

```js
function sum(el) {
  let entrPriceEl = document.getElementById('enterence_price');
  let extraEl = document.getElementById('extra');
  let priceEl = document.getElementById('price');
  let result;
  if (el.id === "enterence_price" || el.id === "extra") {
    result = parseFloat(entrPriceEl.value) / 100 * parseFloat(extraEl.value);
    if (!isNaN(result)) {
      priceEl.value = result.toFixed(2);
    }
  } else if (el.id === "price") {
    result = (priceEl.value / entrPriceEl.value) * 100;
    if (!isNaN(result)) {
      extraEl.value = result + "%"; 
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<label>Enterence Price<br></label>
<input type="text" id="enterence_price" onkeyup="sum(this);">
<br>
<label>extra%<br></label>
<input type="text" id="extra" value="120%" onkeyup="sum(this);">
<br>

<label>Price<br></label>
<input type="text" id="price" onkeyup="sum(this);">
<br>
```